# connecting points in plot in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

this is a simple task but for some reason it is not giving me the desired output.

```
x1 = c(100000,250000,500000,750000,1000000)
y1 = c(1.076904,3.917412,12.365130,23.084268,37.234246)
plot(y1, pch=5, ylim=c(1,50),xlab="Sample Size", ylab="Time(s)" , main = "Time relative to Sample Size-NonGreedy", xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at=1:5, labels = x1)
lines(x1,y1, col = "gray")
```

I want to plot x1,y1 and connect the points with a line, but the line is not 
showing. 
I am using axes because I want these specific labels to show.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to give the x-coordinates to plot as well.
Also you have to modify the `at` argument in your axis function.

```
   x1 = c(100000,250000,500000,750000,1000000)
    y1 = c(1.076904,3.917412,12.365130,23.084268,37.234246)
    plot(x1, y1, pch=5, ylim=c(1,50),xlab="Sample Size", ylab="Time(s)" , main = "Time relative to Sample Size-NonGreedy", xaxt = "n")
    axis(1, at = x1, labels = x1)
    lines(x1, y1, col = "gray")
```

Note that you can specify `type = "b"`

```
plot(x1, y1, pch = 5, ylim=c(1,50),xlab="Sample Size", ylab="Time(s)" , 
     main = "Time relative to Sample Size-NonGreedy", xaxt = "n", type = "b")
```

to get lines and points at once.

Comment: Oh yes type="b" thanks! but do you have an idea why the way I did it isn't working?

Comment: yes, because you basically just wrote `plot(y1)` instead of `plot(x1, y1)`. In this case R picks 1:5 as default x values.
Therefore the lines function did not show the line because the the "true" x values were not on the plot.

Comment: Yes I did that because I want the x-axis to have the exact numbers in x1 so I used axis to place these values on the x-axis. Any idea whether I can plot(x,y)
and control what labels appear on the x-axis?

Comment: `axis` only puts the values on the axis. But the values have to be already there (invisible in the background). That's why you have to specify them in the plot. 
Otherwise R picks the x values.